# How to use PhpSpreadsheet in cakephp2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I Tried Many Thing To Implement PhpSpreadsheet in CakePHP 2.x , In CakePHP 4 It Worked For Me.

Finally I Tried things mentioned in given link blog

http://abakalidis.blogspot.com/2018/08/how-to-use-latest-phpofficespreadsheet.html

It solve all issue but it generating Xlsx file. For XLS it worked.

After putting PHPSpreadsheet SOrce TO Vender In App Folder.

I Use Following Code

```
<?php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$spreadsheet->createSheet();
$writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
?>
```

For XLS I Replace 3 lines as below

```
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xls($spreadsheet);
$spreadsheet->createSheet();
$writer->save('hello world.xls');
?>
```

This Code Worked , But For Xlsx It IS giving Error

Comment: What does "not able to use" mean? What have you tried?

Comment: I Have Updated Details In main Que.

Comment: This is better. But what error does it give?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

PhpSpreadsheet was installed with composer:

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

In `composer.json` just add:

```json
 "require": {
     "google/apiclient": "^2.12.1",
     "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.25"
 }
```

Trick was to add public `$components = array('GoogleAPI');` at the beginning of the controller class. Then you just use:

```
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory
```

I.e.,

```
$objPHPExcel = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load(YOUR_FILE);
```